# Out of memory reading a set of heatmaps, storing into panda dataframe ( Python )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory, heatmap

I'm trying to read all heatmaps defined by filenames in a CSV - present in a panda dataframe - but getting an Out of Memory error from Ptyhon. I have created the following 2 methods to read a heatmap and convert it into a list of intensity values per pixel:

```
def heatmap_to_vector(filename):
    img = Image.open(r'C:\path\to\heatmaps\'+filename).convert('RGBA')
        
    # get values as list
    arr = list(img.getdata()) 
    
    # convert each RGB tuple to an intensity (float) value
    heatmap_vector = [get_heatmap_pixel_value(x) for x in arr]
            
    return heatmap_vector

def get_heatmap_pixel_value(pixel):
    (r, g, b, a) = pixel
    return (255+r-b)/(510)
```

Then I apply the heatmap_to_vector method to every filename in the panda dataframe to convert each heatmap filename to the corresponding heatmap's values ( as a list of floats representing intensity values for each pixel ):

```
def preprocess_heatmaps(df):
    for i in heatmap_columns:
        df[i] = df[i].apply(heatmap_to_vector)
```

When running my preprocess_heatmaps method on my pandas dataframe, I'm getting an "Out of memory" error though. How can I make my code more memory-efficient? I'm running this code on about 4.000 heatmaps, which all are stored in PNG format and have their filenames present in the panda dataframe that I feed to preprocess_heatmaps. Each heatmap is about 300x200 pixels.

Perhaps my code is using unnecessarily much memory, or it just requires a huge amount of memory to store these values?
If anyone could help me out on how this can be done more memory-efficiently, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you converting to a list of floats? That will use *significantly* more memory than the corresponding `numpy.ndarray` object.... Doesn't pillow support numpy arrays natively? Does `numpy.array(img.getdata())` work? If so, just work with `numpy` arrays. What else is in your dataframe? Please provide specific details.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the input, I didn't know about that so I will try to adjust it to simply a numpy array to see if that solves it!